# How to install Intel XDK on ubuntu linux - install_gui.sh is missing

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, intel-xdk

Can anyone give me any information has to how to install the current version of the intel XDK on Ubuntu Linux 14.04 LTS?

The download page states that after extracting the archive I should execute install_gui.sh but that file is not included in either the 32 or 64 bit download.

There is a file called install.sh but this requires arguments and I can't find any documentation as to how I should use it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to run the install.sh without any arguments. It will bring up a GUI installer.

Comment: I did not test this on Ubuntu 14, but on an existing Ubuntu 13 VM I've got running. I did run into a little problem, but am not sure if it is related to the script or my VM. To get around it, I ran the install.sh script as sudo.

Comment: Got it, thanks. New to linux, I needed to specify ./install.sh rather than install to run the correct program.