# Dev Story - Hack the Code can't open DevStory.xdk in Intel XDK

Tags: intel, intel-xdk

I am running Ubuntu Trusty Tahr, and I successfully installed Intel XDK program on my machine. 
To open it though, I need to run a shell script. This is not good, as I need to run an existing .xdk file which I got from:

https://github.com/IntelDevZone/dev-story

throug the Intel XDK. 
What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix this? I would really like to start hacking this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see this post regarding installing the XDK.

[How to install Intel XDK on ubuntu linux - install_gui.sh is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26423584/how-to-install-intel-xdk-on-ubuntu-linux-install-gui-sh-is-missing)

The .xdk file should be opened within the XDK itself.

Comment: exactly what i did the first time. anyway, i managed to get it to work somehow a few days ago